# Rails: Pasting code from one html.erb file to another creates error: undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the code:

```
<a href="http://<%= @app.url %>"><h1><%= @app.name %></h1></a>
```

in show.html.erb and it runs fine. However when I paste that code to newsfeed.html.erb, it gives the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in Reviews#newsfeed

undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

From reading other similar questions I think I need to make a change to reviews_controller.rb. This is (I think) the relevant code in that file:

```
def newsfeed
    @reviews = Review.all
end
```

And the relevant code in the main AppsController

```
require 'Review'

class AppsController < ApplicationController
...
def show

 @app = App.find_by_name(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @app }
 end
end
```

I believe the solution is to add some code below def newsfeed but I'm not sure what to add. Or maybe that's not even the solution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@app is nil. In the show action you set it like so

```
@app = App.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

But you forgot to add it to the newsfeed action!